# chroot from freebsd to linux

Tags: linux, freebsd, chroot, bsd

I was wondering if you could do a chroot from Freebsd to GNU/Linux, because I know that Freebsd also has a compatibility layer for executable GNU/Linux?

Of course provided that there is support to the filesystem and shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install [linux ABI support on FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html), you can simply execute a Linux binary and it looks like a Linux environment for this application, with the exception that user homes are still available.

You can try it yourself and look at the system by simply executing:

```
/compat/linux/bin/bash
```

Type for example `uname -a` and you'll get Linux version information.

I've also heard about [people having Linux running in a FreeBSD jail](http://devil-detail.blogspot.de/2013/08/debian-linux-freebsd-jail-zfs.html?m=1), but I don't know if this really works well. It may come closer to a chroot environment. And there is also [bhyve](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-host-bhyve.html) that does real virtualization.

Comment: thank you, I was interested more than anything to know if a live freebsd could do the chroot on a Linux system

Comment: Linux running in a FreeBSD jail is the point of this question. Is the FreeBSD emulation good enough to run not only run-of-the-mill applications, but system binaries such as systemd?

Comment: The ABI layer is very powerful and give full compatibility. But do not confuse it with a hypervisor. A jail is a different beast entirely and not related to the ABI. You can run ABI in a Jail - but it is not a VM. A nice explanation of the ABI here: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-emulation/article.html

Comment: @oscarandrea The FreeBSD livefs CD does not have the Linux base packages that are needed, if I remember correctly. You should install FreeBSD and follow the manual that I referenced above.

Comment: @Gilles No, you cannot run very low-level software. This is an ABI emulation and not full system emulation. The system is already started and does not need init/systemd. bhyve or VirtualBox might be interesting for you.

Comment: guys have got it wrong, I do not want to emulate throughout the system (init etc) but I just want to do the chroot bash :)